# Which code use for skip the first and last element when read the text file for double not string

Tags: java, arrays

I got stuck to sum all the double element in the text file and skip first and last element no string please.

This is the text file:

8.7 6.5 0.1 3.2 5.7 9.9 8.3 6.5 6.5 1.5

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0

I want to sum and skip first and last.

```
   Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Name\\DataGym.in.txt"));
   int maxIndx = -1;
   String text[] = new String[1000];

   while(sf.hasNext()) {
   maxIndx++;
   text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine();
}
    sf.close();
  int contestant = 0;

  for (int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(text[j]);
   double sum = 0;
   double answer=0;
   double array[] = new double[1000];

   while(sc.hasNext()){
   Arrays.sort(array);
   double b=sc.nextDouble();  
 } 
 contestant++;
 answer = answer + sum;

  System.out.println("For Competitor #" + contestant + ", the average is " +       (answer/8) );
  }
}
}
```

This is where I got stuck.

Comment: Put `maxIndx++;` after `text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine();`

Comment: Using int j = 1 will skip the first elements and to skip the last one create a simple if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to get the sum. It should return the sum of the numbers in the file excluding the first and last numbers.

```
Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Name\\DataGym.in.txt"));        
int index = 0;
double lastVal = 0.0;
double sum = 0.0;
while (sf.hasNextDouble()) {
    sum = lastVal + sum;
    if (index != 0)
        lastVal = sf.nextDouble();
    else
        sf.nextDouble();
    index++;
    System.out.println(lastVal);
}
sf.close();
```